# onclick on cycle elements and forms in menu don't work on iPad?

Tags: ipad, url, hyperlink, cycle

On my [webshop's home](http://www.onveut.com/) I have 2 problems on iPad :
1) The menu works but the forms in it (connexion and contact) can't be filled
2) The divs with onclick event on them in a cycle (big pictures who scrolls) aren't clickables...

EDIT : 
- The problem occurs only on iOS 7, no problem on iOS 6.
- Some sort of "zone" appears on the places unclickable when we maintain to copy. A very strange zone, like a div who don't exists and don't appears on iOS6 or desktop.
See the picture :
[Here's the problem](http://www.onveut.com/presse/prob_example.png)

Comment: The problem is only under iOS7... not iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !
The problem was due to an iframe for a pop up... It's without any problem on iOS6 and lower, on desktop too...
But I have changed the popup by colorbox to avoid this problem on iOS7.